# Why aren't the lines copied into my system register?

Tags: register, os-clipboard

My copy of Vim has the `+clipboard` feature compiled in:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard
```

I'm trying to copy 1 and 2 lines into system clipboard with the command `1,2y"+`.

[image: An HTML file]

When I check the `+` register with `:reg +`, I get the following output:

[image: A random snippet of Vimscript]

Why aren't the lines copied into my system register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, `"` means start of a comment for :ex commands.

I think you actually want `:1,2y +` as this is the correct syntax for the [`:y` command](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#:y)

Comment: It is not need to add a white space between y and +, `:1,2y +` is equal to `:1,2y+`,verified in vim.